# select rows from a table less than or equal to a specific date and time oracle db

Tags: sql, oracle, date

How can I select rows from a table less than or equal to a specific date and time?

I used the below query:

```
select FILENM,NBR from filerec where TRANS_DT<=TO_DATE('10122017 061000','MMDDYYYY HHMMSS')
```

Here, `TRANS_DT` is `DATE` datatype in the table `filerec`

But it gives me the below error:

> ORA-01810: format code appears twice

I am using Oracle. Can anyone help?

Comment: adding to this, I want to search all the records from this table which loaded before 10/12/2017 6:10:00 AM

Answer (score 1):

You’re using the month indicator (‘MM’) instead of the minute indicator (‘MI’).

Your to_date expression should be:

```
To_date(‘10122017 061000’, ‘MMDDYYYY HH24MISS’)
```

NB, I’ve changed the hours mask to be 24 hours, since you haven’t included an AM/PM in your date string.

Comment: Thanks for your help